What does Qiskit AerSimulator(memory=True) do?
I followed this Qiskit course through Deutsch's algorithm and all seems clear to me except the use of the optional parameter memory=true when making the call to AerSimulator().run(...).
The context of this call is as follows:
def deutsch_algorithm(function: QuantumCircuit):
    """
    Determine if a Deutsch function is constant or balanced.
    """
    qc = compile_circuit(function)

    result = AerSimulator().run(qc, shots=1, memory=True).result()
    measurements = result.get_memory()
    if measurements[0] == "0":
        return "constant"
    return "balanced"

The documentation for AerSimulator does not seem to cover this parameter, since there are so many backed options that most are briefly mentioned and the details are unavailable.
My assumption is that this parameter enables the collection of classical bits from measurements, but I would like to know for certain what happens here.

The parameter memory is used to record and return the measurement outcomes for each shot of the simulation. When you set memory=True, it tells the simulator to save the measurement result from each shot as a separate item in a list.
For example, you can set memory=True and then retrieve the data from memory like so:
# Run and get memory
result = simulator.run(circ, shots=10, memory=True).result()
memory = result.get_memory(circ)
print(memory)

This will print out the list of measurement results, e.g., ['11', '00', '11',...,'11'].
See this documentation for a complete example.
